# Is there a good way to insulate the backplate of a 7915 voltage regulator?

Tags: voltage-regulator

Didn't realise this when I purchased it, but apparently voltage regulators come in two different housings:

[image]

I.e. one that has a metal backplate connected to the input pin and one with a non-conductive backplate. The cooler to which I was planning to attach it, is grounded meaning I would short the input pin to ground.

Any good way to avoid the short (other than biting the bullet and waiting for a new one to be delivered)?

Comment: Use a TO220 mica shim.

Comment: any thin non-conductive material, I suppose, being extra careful about the screw

Comment: Did you try searching the web for "TO220 insulator" ?

Comment: ceramic alumina shim...

Comment: I was thinking of using a piece of tape, but I'd need a plastic screw and I assume it would still need some cooling, which tape isn't exactly great for 

Comment: You can always use a ceramic heatsink. They're not as good as metal ones, but alumina ceramic heatsinks do exist.

Comment: Can yoy disconnect the heatsink from ground?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how.

[image]

The insulator between the device and the heat sink is a mica shim and that between the device and the screw is an insulating bushing.

*Image credit: [Infineon.com](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-Recommendations_for_Board_Assembly_TO-AP-v02_00-EN.pdf?fileId=db3a3043183a955501189e662ae34052)*

Comment: Ok, I get the idea. Think I'll bite the bullet and look for a 7915 with no backplate connection, because I don't really have any thermal pads/insulators or insulating bushings for the screw and household items are a bit too risky.

Comment: A TO-220 insulating kit would be available off-the-shelf.

Comment: And it's cheaper too (pennies anyway).

Comment: @Woodgnome Remember that the TO-220FP package has a *much* higher thermal resistance than the regular TO-220. I would avoid using one unless you don't have any other option.

Comment: The original component used TO-220FP housing, so it should be fine. Though, I ended up stealing a thermal pad from another cooler instead and used that as insulation along with a cable tie instead of a plastic screw.

Answer (score 1):

Mounting TO-220 and similar packages to a heat sink while maintaining electrical isolation is common.  One example is that it allows one large heatsink to host a number of devices, each with a different voltage on its thermal tab.  Or, sometimes the heat sink is grounded yet the device tab has a different voltage present.

The first ingredient is the thermal pad, also called thermal isolator.  You can find them in common package outlines, such as TO-220.  The picture below is an example, in this case Parker Chemtronics 60-11-6956-1674.
[image]

The second ingredient is an isolating shoulder washer.  This is a stepped washer that fits into the TO-220's screw hole and makes sure that your metal screw doesn't touch the tab. The picture below is an example, in this case Keystone Electronics 3049, and permits a typical 4-40 metal screw to mount the package.
[image]

As always, use a multimeter to verify that electrical isolation was achieved between the electrical tab and the heat sink before applying power.